# Accessing View function from internal functions in Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

One of the views in my ember app has the following structure

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        window.onload = function() {
            chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
                receiveGCM(message);
            });
        }
    },
    receiveGCM: function(message){
        console.log(message);
        //type check here
        //Then call necessary data insertion module
        //Or call the notification module
    }
});
```

This is throwing an error `Error in event handler for gcm.onMessage: ReferenceError: receiveGCM is not defined`

Calling `receiveGCM(message)` with the `this` object doesn't solve the problem. Wrong `this` object gets referred. I tried using `bind(this)`. But that doesn't help.

How do I call `receiveGCM()` from the chrome listener method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive binding of this object solves the problem.

```
window.onload = function() {
            chrome.gcm.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
                this.receiveGCM(message);
            }.bind(this));
        }.bind(this)
```

But this restricts the usage of chrome's this object inside the listener. As long it's not used, this solution will work.